# How to select overlapping objects

Tags: selection-tools

If you duplicate an object in edit mode with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and then hit <kbd>P</kbd> to make it its own object, it deselects and remains in place over/with the original object. What’s the keyboard move to determine/select the duplicate object from the original one (not using the outline)? Andrew Price does this too fast to figure out.

Comment: Link to the video would be helpful

Comment: In Object mode, you can determine them by names (written in the bottom left) *or* you can right click on the object while pressing `Alt`. Objects' list located in that place will appear

Comment: video link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6lNoOZGF3x4 video link

Comment: starting at 11:16 when he duplicates an edge.

Comment: In that case it can be selected (and it seems to me it really was) just by `RMB` - if you remember where it's placed, you can easily find it like that

Comment: I tried that. But since it's now placed over/with the orig. edge I get the "wrong" one most of the time. Was hoping for an easier method.

Answer (score 7):

If multiple objects are very close together or even overlapping entirely and visually indistinguishable from one another, you can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + right click to get a drop-down menu that allows you to choose from a list of objects in that area.

In the screen shot below there are actually two identical cubes overlapping. The menu lets us choose which one to select.

[image: Alt+RMB brings up the Select Menu]

[More on this and other selection methods in the Blender Reference Manual.](http://www.blender.org/manual/modeling/objects/selecting.html)

Comment: I am/was aware of the Alt + right click. However, the video shows no use of the RMB, so something else is happening, or, he's moving so fast the display doesn't show it. All for now, still hoping for Andrew's secret move.

Comment: No secret move.  :-)  After selecting the edge loop he duplicates it, then hits Esc so it jumps back to its original location. Next he hits P to separate only the duplicated edge loop into its own object. Then he tabs out into Object Mode and can select either of the two objects.

Comment: "can select either..." Agreed, but  aside from the Alt+right click layer menu, which he "apparently/visibly" does not use, he quickly selected the edge he wanted. Question: when making a duplicate is the duplicate placed on top or behind the original object? IOW, will I get one or the other when selecting after a duplication or is it hit or miss?

Comment: btw, forgot to ask in prev. comment. When he hits Esc, is that the actual Esc key, or is it simply a right click?

Comment: He didn't need to use Alt+RMB because there were only two objects to pick from. Blender is smart enough to guess you want to select the one you don't already have selected. Esc key and RMB both cancel an edit (while Enter key and LMB both accept an edit). Take your pick of mouse or keyboard. Hope this helps.