# If I press Shift + D to duplicate an object will it always be just one copy?

Tags: modeling, selection-tools

If I press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> many times and then click the Right Mouse Button, will I have many duplicated objects in the same place, or will it be only one duplicated object?

I ask because if there are many duplicated objects in the same place, how can I then select each one of them?  In *object mode* I can select each object by right clicking on it.

Comment: Yes they will all be copied in the same exact place. The best way to select them all would be through the outliner.

Comment: You can right click on the place with multiple objects while holding Alt which will bring a pop up menu with objects available under cursor position, e.g. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36676/how-to-select-overlapping-objects

Comment: If what you want to do is delete the duplicates, then do **Remove Doubles**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A duplicate will be created every time you press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> and right or left click the mouse button.

If you only press Shift+D multiple times, but only click the mouse once, only one duplicate will be made.

If you're in ***Object Mode***, then you can just right click each one as you said.

If you're in ***Edit Mode*** then right click to select one of the vertices and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>.  This will select all the geometry connected to that vertex.  Since none of the duplicates are connected, it will select each duplicated instance:

[image]