# How to select overlapping objects in 2.8+?

Tags: objects, interface, selection-tools, select

I've found this answer: [How to select overlapping objects](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/36676/how-to-select-overlapping-objects)

Unfortunately it doesn't work for me. I `Alt+RMB` and `Alt+LMB` but nothing happens. And the official document linked in the answer is not alive anymore. How to do this in 2.8? Is this shortcut configurable? What's its name in keymapping?

Comment: Just tested it in 2.93. In Object mode, it's still Alt+LMB (or Alt+RMB for right-click select). With additional clicks at the same spot, you can cycle through the stacked objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its name is just `Select` in keymapping. More specifically, this one:

[image]

Perhaps I accidentally changed it.